# My textures are rendering transparent and strange

Tags: rendering, shaders, render-layers

I am trying to make this cool minecraft effect on blender. I've done all the modeling and tracking. In rendered view it looks fine.
[image: What it should look like]

But it comes out very weird. I am using blender 2.8 for this project. It has nothing to do with the materials, because I changed them around and tested it out. I have a feeling it has something to do with either the movie clip editor, sequence editor, or the render settings.[image: Broken rendered strange image]

I've been trying over and over to fix it. While it renders it looks fine, but as soon as it finishes, it comes out with nothing but rendered shadows, but I have not enabled shadow catcher. I have done research and I don't think it is a common problem. If you can help me, please do.

[image]

This was the default setup of the compositing nodes.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your compositing nodes.

Comment: Something must be messed up in your compositor

Comment: if all else fails, create a new file and append each component from the old one, one at a time.

Comment: Eevee or Cycles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted all of the nodes, and simplified it. Use Alpha over instead of Add.

[image: Fixed]